# Some place ids are not being recognised with Javascript Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

I'm developing a little app around the Google Maps API... I've a good understanding of how the API works however i've ran into a small problem i was hoping i could ask about here.

I'm performing a nearby search (which is working and returning all the correct places i'm expecting, and they plot successfully on my map instance) below:

```
request = {
            location: current_position,
            radius: 750,
            type: ['restaurant']
        };

        service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
```

I'm then calling a function in my callback function to get each place details based on the place id:

```
getPlaceDetailsById(place_id);

function getPlaceDetailsById(place_id) {

var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.getDetails({

    placeId: place_id
}, function(place, status) {



if (place) { do stuff } else { console.log(place_id; console.log("No place available);}
```

This is where the problem is occuring; some place ids that i'm passing to the .getDetails function are not being recognised.

> ChIJkxjoZGcEYUgRlbQuhAp5jwY
>   No place available

However if i manually put this place id in replace of the place_id parameter for the getDetails function it returns it as expected.

Is there something i can do about this? Appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.  Are you throttling your requests to avoid the query rate limit?

Comment: No i'm not throttling the requests. It's the same place ids everytime too that don't get "Recognised". 8 of them come through fine with full details and if i query the "unrecognised" place ids manually they come back fine too.

Comment: Are the ones that don't get recognized the last ones requested?  Are you checking the status on the result of the request? I'm guessing you are getting `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT`.

Comment: They are the first ones - I am checking the status yes.

Comment: Second request: please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.